# wish to extend the css div and merge it into header

Tags: html, css

http://devoirtechnologies.in/localhealthorganization/Untitled.png

I have just started to learn css so, currently i am facing lot of problem. 
for image like this, i wish that the background is of grey color,center space is of white color and red, blue and pink should be between white part, the code i tried is

```
<body style="background-color:#E6E6E6">

<div class="page" style="background-color:white; margin-left:18%; margin-right:18%; height:100%;">

        <div style="background-color:pink; margin-left:18%; margin-right:18%;">
            <p>demo text </p>
        </div>

</div>

</body>
```

But i went wrong in the beginning itself and i am not able to rectify it. can anyone please tell me how i can code a page like this

Comment: can you post a fiddle please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to play around with the colors and the actual values to match but here is a template:

```
 <!-- Define your own background -->
<body style="background-color: yellow;">
    <div class="container" style="background-color: white; margin: 5%;">
        <div class="header">
            <!--- This is your header -->
            <div style="height: 100px;">
                <img src="..." alt="Logo Space"/>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: red; width: 100%; min-height: 100px;">
                The red bar
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page" style="background-color: white; ">
            <div style="float: left; margin: 5%; width: 25%; background-color: blue; min-height: 400px;">
                The blue sidebar
            </div>

            <div style="float: left; margin: 5%; width: 50%; background-color: pink; min-height: 200px;">
                The pink content
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9o645fe9/3/

Good luck!

#### Edit

But in an ideal world, you don't really want to do mix css and html together

```
body {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.container {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
}
.logo-space {
    height: 100px;
}
.header-red {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
}
.blue-sidebar {
    float: left;
    margin: 5%;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: blue;
    min-height: 400px;
}
.pink-content {
    float: left;
    margin: 5%;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: pink;
    min-height: 200px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo-space">
                <img src="..." alt="Logo Space"/>
            </div>
            <div class="header-red">
            The red stripe
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page">
            <div class="blue-sidebar">
            </div>
            <div class="pink-content">
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vL1pu6da/

Comment: it is covering the whole screen, whereas i wish the background to be of different color and the white color should be in between and other colors b/w white part

Comment: Updated is this what you mean?

Comment: I'd have given you a +1 had you not written all of your CSS inline

Comment: @user3774056 Has that helped? Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @Dawid O it wasn't exactly what i was looking for, but it helped me in understand the concept

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is a common way of formatting a page like you ask:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="nav">Nav</div>
    <div class="content"> Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:grey;
}
.container {
    margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 80%:
}
.header {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
.nav, .content {
    float:left;
}
.nav {
    width:20%;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 300px;
}
.content {
    width: 80%;
    background-color:yellow;
    height: 300px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5kpqbut/1/)

Comment: the design you showed goes through out the page, where as i want the background to be gray, the center part should be white, and red blue and pink color code should be inside white part (as shown in my design)